# Is it possible to create a Nodequeue of Nodequeues?

Tags: 7, nodes, queue

I have a number of node queues that serve as collections of nodes. I want the user to be able to take those collections (node queues) and add them to a queue, essentially allowing the user to have a node queue of node queues. Is this possible? If not, are there ay recommendations on how I might implement something like this?

also, I'm using drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nodequeue](http://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) supports Smartqueues.

> Smartqueue API
>
> Nodequeue provides a robust API that allows other modules to define
>   smartqueues, which are associated with external data. For example, the
>   included taxonomy smartqueue creates subqueues for a given queue for
>   every term in the chosen vocabulary. Nodes are then only eligible for
>   subqueues whose term matches the nodes terms. This makes it very easy
>   to have queues for each category without cluttering the management
>   page.

If the default smartqueue's dont meet your needs you could leverage the API to write your own smartqueue that uses the queue's you've made for your users.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps see [Smartqueue for Content Types](https://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_nodetypes).

> This module provides a smartqueues based on avaliable content types.
>   It adds a subqueue per node of selected content type to hold an
>   ordered queue for nodes of another types. Any of these types can be
>   used for smartqueues as well to hold additional levels of nodes
>   grouping. So you can build very complex informational structures
>   powered by handy Nodequeue's features and integration.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using d7

Comment: both modules have D7 code ... https://drupal.org/node/1381540. If these dont mean your needs -- implement your own.

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried the d7 patch but I'm getting fatal errors. I do realize that it's possible to roll my own, just want to make sure that there is no existing way to do this first

Comment: .... did you read the whole issue queue? the patch is based on this sandbox https://drupal.org/sandbox/lynn/1822216 Does that provide you errors as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but I did this on my site by having a node (a new content type called "Collections") that is associated with each queue. I needed this so I could have an author, description, date, and other metadata for each collection.

Then I made one more queue that can only contain nodes of type = collection. This is only worth it if you want the benefit of the collection nodes, of course. You can see it in action at http://hastac.org/collections